# How do you calculate the reflectivity of material from its conductivity?

Tags: reflection, conductors, electronics

How do you calculate the reflectivity of material from its conductivity? For example, gold at v=9x10^12/s
(this problem is from the electronic property of material by Hummel). Is it possible to use 'Hagen-Rubens equation'?